# What vs. Which - correct usage in questions

Tags: usage, questions

Today I found myself in a situation that I asked "**Which** class" to a friend who said that "we are going to the class". Then one of my friends said that I should ask "**what** class" and another one said both (what class and which class) are correct. Who is right?

This issue I meet often when I'm talking about things, such as:

> **What** day/ **which** day?
>
> **What** floor / **which** floor?
>
> **what** teacher / **which** teacher?
>
> **What** page / **which** page?
>
> **What** place / **which** place?
>
> **What** line (bus) / **Which** line?
>
> **What** /**which** sentence (do you agree with)?

Answer (score 6):

This is actually a rather simple answer although it's rarely explained in simple terms:

***What*** seeks the answer from an undefined set while ***which*** asks you to choose among possible options. (Additionally, you could ask ***which*** when discussing people.)

For instance, to use your first example, let's say that I was making an appointment with a friend:

```
"What day are we meeting?"
"I'm available on Tuesdays and Thursdays."
"Which one works best for you?"
```

Comment: I should emphasize that the set of possible options can actually be quite large. For instance, when your friend asks what/which class you're taking, either usage is acceptable if we're referring to many possible options. If your friend asked for the class that you were taking to fulfill a requirement in the chemistry department, then 'which' is more appropriate for a more limited set of options.

Comment: A rather nice, concise, and cogent explanation.  I think I'll steal it  :)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But still I do not find the way to apply your things in the reality because all of the examples that I put on the post are a matter of options. (i.e. always when I ask about a day, floor, teacher, and page etc. it's necessary that I have options such as: day from other days, floor from other floors, teacher from other teachers and pages from other pages etc.). So in the end of the day, I don't understand how I can use your answer in fact.

Comment: The keywords here is **set**. If I asked you, "What kind of art do you like?" then I would be asking a very open-ended question. On the other hand, I could ask you "Which kind of art do you like?" In this instance, it would be a strange question unless your options were limited (a *defined set* of options). In fact, there are many instances where the words are interchangeable but we're talking about a *tendency* in usage.

Answer (score 0):

My English is not very good but I understood that `Which` should be used when we are talking about `possible options` . @  `What` : undefined .

@ what day? : can be any from Monday to Sunday
@ which day ? : when we know we can only choose between certain days

@ what floor? : could be any floor in that building
@ which floor?: when you know that that Hospital has 5 floors and you are looking after Pediatric Department which could be either floor 1 or floor 2 ;

@ I hope it makes sense . Is what I understood from those previous explanations .