# 'on what' or 'on which' floor are you?

Tags: interrogatives, wh-questions

Our college is a tall building and sometimes friends tell me that they are waiting for me somewhere there. Not always I'm not sure about the floor that he or she is on. So I would like to know how to ask them about it, using the correct question word (what or which):

> *Choice 1*: **On** **what** floor are you?
>
> *Choice 2*: **On** **which** floor are you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What vs. Which - correct usage in questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/110746/what-vs-which-correct-usage-in-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really makes no difference to the meaning of the question which of the two you use, in today's common usage. Using 'which' sounds slightly more proper to me. I imagine that if the Queen of England were asking the question, that's how she would ask it. Needless to say, most of us don't speak like the Queen.

If you want to sound more natural you would probably say

> Which floor are you on?

or

> What floor are you on?

The prepositions are at the ends of these two sentences, which we are often told is incorrect. Still, most English speakers will say it that way in casual conversation.